# Line intersection function

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I have a line line intersection function (infinite lines) of which both lines are defined by two points.

It does not seem to find the correct intersection point but I don't know where I have gone wrong. I created the function following the math explanation on Wikipedia:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line

This is my attempt at making the function from the math:

```
//https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line
//subscript 1 = a1
//subscript 2 = a2
//subscript 3 = b1
//subscript 4 = b2

    public static bool TryGetIntersectingPoint(Vector2 a1, Vector2 a2, Vector2 b1, Vector2 b2, out Vector2 hitPoint)
    {
        hitPoint = Vector2.zero;

        // determinant
        float d = (a1.x-a2.x)*(b1.y-b2.y) - (a1.y-b2.y)*(b1.x-b2.x);

        // check if lines are parallel
        if (Approximately(d, epsilon)) return false;

        float px = (a1.x * a2.y - a1.y * a2.x) * (b1.x-b2.x) - (a1.x - a2.x) * (b1.x * b2.y - b1.y * b2.x);
        float py = (a1.x * a2.y - a1.y * a2.x) * (b1.y-b2.y) - (a1.y - a2.y) * (b1.x * b2.y - b1.y * b2.x);

        hitPoint = new Vector2(px,py) / d;
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the visual of the result as you can see the red point is not in the correct location of intersection.

[image]

I am not sure where I have gone wrong, hope someone might have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: `a1.y-b2.y` should say `a1.y-a2.y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```cs
float d = (a1.x-a2.x)*(b1.y-b2.y) - (a1.y-b2.y)*(b1.x-b2.x);
```

should instead be

```cs
float d = (a1.x-a2.x)*(b1.y-b2.y) - (a1.y-a2.y)*(b1.x-b2.x);
```